# Python: Using bool() to select which vars are TRUE, then use those values to call function

Tags: python, string, formatting, boolean, callable

First question ever!  I've built a GUI which asks user to input 2 of possible 5 values.  Each pair of values (10 possible pairs) get used to run 10 different solution functions named Case_n to which all five values (both zero and non-zero) are passed.
The problem I'm having is getting the bool() results stripped down to 2 digit without brackets, etc and then placed into a variable used to create the name of the function to call.
I've run the logic, with TRUE values added to a list, then converted the list to a string so I could strip it down to just the numerals, saved the 2 digit string and added it to the Case_n name.  Now, when I try to use the name to call the function, I get an error that a string is not callable.  Please help . . .

````
  s = 5    #vars.  For this example, I've pre-loaded 2 of them
  a = 15
  l = 0
  r = 0
  e_deg = 0
  ve = 0


  case = []
  if bool(s):
      case.append(1)
  if bool(a):
      case.append(2)
  if bool(l):
    case.append(3)
  if bool(r):
     case.append(4)
  if bool(e_deg):
      case.append(5)
  
  nm = str(case)  # placeholder to convert case to string
  case_num = nm[1] + nm[4]  # this returns 12 as a string

  # create case_num var, using the string

  Case = "Case_" + case_num
  print("Case = ",Case)         # Should be Case_12


  def Case_12(s,a,l,r,e_deg,ve):
      print("Case_12 running")  

  Case(s,a,l,r,e_deg,ve)  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `eval(Case)` but I advise against it as you are processing user input and it could be a security risk.
An easy way would be to build the following dict :

```
my_dict = {"Case_1": Case_1, ..., "Case_12" : Case_12}
```

And then, instead of calling Case, you would do

```
my_dict[Case](s,a,l,r,e_deg,ve)
```

You could also create a function :

```
def choose_case(my_case_as_str):
   my_case_dict = {"Case_1": Case_1, ..., "Case_12": Case_12}

   return my_case_dict[my_case_as_str]
```

And then call

```
choose_case(Case)(s,a,l,r,e_deg,ve)
```

By the way, you probably don't want your function and variable names to start with an uppercase letter. You also probably want to use a safer way to get user input (for example use [Template str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings))

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful solutions.  I look forward to working through them. P

Comment: Thanks again Gabriel.  I implemented the dictionary method and it works fine.  It's a bit less code than my original approach, but I'm still curious whether there is a simpler solution that doesn't involve converting to string and stripping the extra characters.

Comment: def get_case_number(l):
    my_case = l[0]*10 + l[1]
    return "Case_{:d}".format(my_case). And then get_case_number(case) : Like this, you get the case withouth having to do the manual conversion

Comment: Gabriel, Thanks for the variation.  So far, the converting to string and then using a dict is the least amount of code and is working well.  :  ) P